# C++ enable_shared_from_this can be private inherited?

Tags: c++, private

```
 class A: private enable_shared_from_this < A > {
   public: shared_ptr < A > func() {
     return shared_from_this();
   }
 }
```

Is this private inherit is better than public inherit, just like private inherit unCopyable, we just utilize the `enable_shared_from_this<A>`, while others always public inherit from `enable_shared_from_this`?

Comment: Only if you don't expect it to work.